# If a set spans the vector space, and is contained in the linear span of another set, then the second set also spans

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be subsets of a vector space $V$. Assume that $\text{Span} (S_1) = V$ and that every vector in $S_1$ is in $ \text{Span} (S_2)$. Show that $V = \text{Span}(S_2)$

So I said let $x$ be a vector in $\text{Span}(S_2)$

This implies that $x$ is a linear combination of vectors

Which would then have to mean $x$ is in $\text{Span} (S_1) $

And since we know $\text{Span} (S_1) = V$ then $\text{Span} (S_2) = V$

I know the notation could be better, but I am on a tablet and my latex is bad

Comment: when you say "x is a linear combination of vectors"... which vectors are you talking about? Moreover, if you start with a vector in $S2$ and you show the vector is in $V$, you prove $span(S2) \subseteq V$. And that is not what we want.

Comment: X would be a linear combination of the vectors in S2, but the fact that it is a linear means it would also satisfy the condition of Span (S1)

Answer (score 3):

Since $S_1\subseteq\text{span}(S_2)$, $V=\text{span}(S_1)\subseteq\text{span}(S_2)$; so $V=\text{span}(S_2)$ since $\text{span}(S_2)\subseteq V$.

Comment: I thought about that being the case, but how do we know that Span(S1) is contained in Span (S2)? The assumption only says  that S1 is in span (S2)

Comment: $span(S_1)$ is the smallest subspace of V containing $S_1$; so since $S_1$ is contained in $span(S_2)$, $span(S_1)$ is contained in $span(S_2)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a different answer.

> Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be subsets of a vector space $V$. Assume that $\text{Span} (S_1) = V$ and that every vector in $S_1$ is in $ \text{Span} (S_2)$. Show that $V = \text{Span}(S_2)$

I am assuming everything finite here, i.e., $S_1 = \{v^{(1)}_1,\ldots, v^{(1)}_n\}$ and $S_2 = \{v^{(2)}_1,\ldots, v^{(2)}_m\}$.

Proof:
Let $w$ in $V$.
Since $\text{Span} (S_1) = V$,

$$w = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v^{(1)}_i$$

But $v^{(1)}_i \in \text{Span}(S_2)$, so

$$v^{(1)}_i = \sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij} v^{(2)}_j$$

Using both we get

$$w = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij} v^{(2)}_j \\
= \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{ij} v^{(2)}_j$$

But now $w$ can be written as a linear combination of $v^{(2)}_j \in S_2$:

$$w = \sum_{j=1}^m c_i v^{(2)}_j$$

In which $c_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{ij}$.

Since $w$ was arbitrary, $V = \text{Span}(S_2)$.
$\square$